# Text Adventure, enemy stats not storing/updating from one method to another?

Tags: c#, text, methods, updating, adventure

I have a system here that randomly generates an enemy character with random traits involving their race, gender, etc. When the string array enemyRace chooses one of the options I have a block of if-statements made to modify the health, defense, and money of whatever race is chosen.

Once that is finished it should display that information at the bottom in the EnemyStats() method but it doesn't, all stats show up as 0. I initialize the two methods in my Start class in the Main method.

Can you guys help to properly display its stats? Is it due to the fact that the methods are void? I'm still new to C# so any guidance will be appreciated.

**class Start** (Contains Main method)

```
        // Loading in objects 
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy();

        // Loading in the game

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to create a new character . . . ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        // Game Loop
        enemy.EnemySpawn();
        enemy.EnemyStats();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

**class Enemy**

```
    Random random = new Random();

    // Enemy Base Stats
    public static int enemyHP;
    public static int enemyEP;
    public static int enemyCoins;

    // Enemy Attack
    public static int enemyMelee = 0;
    public static int enemyMagic = 0;
    public static int enemyRange = 0;

    // Enemy Defense
    public static int enemyMeleeDefense = 0;
    public static int enemyMagicDefense = 0;
    public static int enemyRangeDefense = 0;

    public void EnemySpawn()
    {

        string[] enemyGender = { "Male ", "Female " };
        string[] enemyRace = { "Human ", "Elf ", "Dwarf ", "Gnome ", "Halfling ", "Half-Elf ", "Half-Orc " };
        string[] enemyClass = { "Ranger", "Paladin", "Thief", "Mage", "Shaman", "Warlock", "Cleric", "Druid", "Monk", "Bard", "Mercenary", "Merchant" };

        // Determines if class is Melee, Magic, Healer, or Clerk
        int enemyClassChance = random.Next(1, 4);

        if (enemyRace.ToString() == "Human ")
        {
            enemyHP += 100;
            enemyEP += 80;
            enemyCoins += 10;

            enemyMelee += 5;
            enemyMagic += 5;
            enemyRange += 5;

            enemyMeleeDefense += 6;
            enemyMagicDefense += 5;
            enemyRangeDefense += 6;
        }
        else if (enemyRace.ToString() == "Elf ")
        {
            enemyHP += 90;
            enemyEP += 90;
            enemyCoins += 10;

            enemyMelee += 5;
            enemyMagic += 9;
            enemyRange += 8;

            enemyMeleeDefense += 4;
            enemyMagicDefense += 8;
            enemyRangeDefense += 4;
        }
        else if (enemyRace.ToString() == "Dwarf ")
        {
            enemyHP += 125;
            enemyEP += 100;
            enemyCoins += 10;

            enemyMelee += 8;
            enemyMagic += 5;
            enemyRange += 5;

            enemyMeleeDefense += 8;
            enemyMagicDefense += 3;
            enemyRangeDefense += 4;
        }
        else if (enemyRace.ToString() == "Gnome ")
        {
            enemyHP += 95;
            enemyEP += 80;
            enemyCoins += 10;

            enemyMelee += 4;
            enemyMagic += 8;
            enemyRange += 4;

            enemyMeleeDefense += 2;
            enemyMagicDefense += 6;
            enemyRangeDefense += 5;
        }
        else if (enemyRace.ToString() == "Halfling ")
        {
            enemyHP += 80;
            enemyEP += 75;
            enemyCoins += 10;

            enemyMelee += 3;
            enemyMagic += 10;
            enemyRange += 7;

            enemyMeleeDefense += 1;
            enemyMagicDefense += 9;
            enemyRangeDefense += 4;
        }
        else if (enemyRace.ToString() == "Half-Elf ")
        {
            enemyHP += 95;
            enemyEP += 80;
            enemyCoins += 10;

            enemyMelee += 2;
            enemyMagic += 8;
            enemyRange += 8;

            enemyMeleeDefense += 5;
            enemyMagicDefense += 8;
            enemyRangeDefense += 2;
        }
        else if (enemyRace.ToString() == "Half-Orc ")
        {
            enemyHP += 150;
            enemyEP += 125;
            enemyCoins += 10;

            enemyMelee += 10;
            enemyMagic += 1;
            enemyRange += 4;

            enemyMeleeDefense += 10;
            enemyMagicDefense += 1;
            enemyRangeDefense += 5;
        }

        switch (enemyClassChance)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine(enemySpawnText[random.Next(0, enemySpawnText.Length)] + enemyGender[random.Next(0, enemyGender.Length)] +
                                  enemyRace[random.Next(0, enemyRace.Length)] + enemyClassMelee[random.Next(0, enemyClassMelee.Length)] + ".");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine(enemySpawnText[random.Next(0, enemySpawnText.Length)] + enemyGender[random.Next(0, enemyGender.Length)] +
                                  enemyRace[random.Next(0, enemyRace.Length)] + enemyClassMagic[random.Next(0, enemyClassMagic.Length)] + ".");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine(enemySpawnText[random.Next(0, enemySpawnText.Length)] + enemyGender[random.Next(0, enemyGender.Length)] +
                                  enemyRace[random.Next(0, enemyRace.Length)] + enemyClassHealer[random.Next(0, enemyClassHealer.Length)] + ".");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine(enemySpawnText[random.Next(0, enemySpawnText.Length)] + enemyGender[random.Next(0, enemyGender.Length)] +
                                  enemyRace[random.Next(0, enemyRace.Length)] + enemyClassClerk[random.Next(0, enemyClassClerk.Length)] + ".");
                break;
        }

    }

    public void EnemyStats()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("##################### ");
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy Statistics: ");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Melee:       {0}", enemyMelee);
        Console.WriteLine("Magic:       {0}", enemyMagic);
        Console.WriteLine("Range:       {0}", enemyRange);
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Melee Defense:       {0}", enemyMeleeDefense);
        Console.WriteLine("Magic Defense:       {0}", enemyMagicDefense);
        Console.WriteLine("Range Defense:       {0}", enemyRangeDefense);
        Console.WriteLine("##################### ");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. The majority of the code isn't relevant here - please show a complete program, but *just* what's required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Also, try stepping through in a debugger first. Note that calling `ToString()` on a string array probably isn't going to do what you expect it to... (How do you think you're randomly choosing a race? The only aspect that's random at the moment is the class... and that can currently never be a clerk.)

Comment: Putting `ToString` randomly in your code, just so it compiles, doesn't make it work. Every piece of code has meaning, and that meaning is not "Please, make this compiler error go away!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `EnemySpawn()` method instead of :

```
 if (enemyRace.ToString() == "Human ")
```

replace in every condition (i.e. in `if` block use `enemyClassChance` as index like below)

```
if (enemyRace[enemyClassChance].ToString() == "Human ")
```

Also , I believe instead of

```
 int enemyClassChance = random.Next(1, 4);
```

it should be :

```
int enemyClassChance = random.Next(1, enemyRace.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it works properly now. Although I'm still confused as to why using (1, 4) didn't work yet (1, enemyRace.Length) did? Also how does the index come into play?

Comment: basically int enemyClassChance = random.Next(1, enemyRace.Length); gets the random number between 1 and length of enemyrace array which is count of elements in your array i.e 7.  And now the if condition has enemyRace[enemyClassChance].ToString() , say random number is three which means enemyRace[3].ToString() will be equal to 4th element in enemyRace array i.e "Gnome ".

Comment: Ah of course, the index flew right over my head, so thanks that makes sense now! I also modifed the class a lot like removing the switch statement, changing the enemyClassChance to enemyRaceChance so it makes more sense and making a single array containing all class types and making a similar if-statement block with all the classes. Appreciate the answer!